# Libcurl: image is damaged when using fstream::write instead of fwrite

Tags: c++, libcurl, fstream

I'm trying to download image file from a url. I followed the example using `fwrite` and it succeeded. Now I'm trying to use `fstream::write` to save the data (`ios::binary`), but **the data is damaged**. Here is my code:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, char* out) {
    //void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, File* fp
   
    fstream file;
    if (file.is_open()){
        file.close();
        file.clear();
    }
    file.open(out, ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open()){
        cout << "open successfully\n" << endl;
        
        file.write((char*)ptr, nmemb*size);  // Does it correct?
    };
    // fwrite(ptr,size,nmemb,fp);
    file.close();
    file.clear();
    cout <<"\n sizeof(ptr): " << sizeof(ptr) //size of ptr[0]?
         <<"\n sizeof(char): " << sizeof(char)
         <<"\n size: " << size
         <<"\n nmemb: " << nmemb<< endl;
         return size*nmemb;
}
```

I'm confused about the parameters in write_data.
According to [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html)

> `size_t  write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);`
>
> "`ptr` points to the delivered data, and the size of that data is `size` multiplied with `nmemb`."

......so what are the meanings of size and nmemb?

When tried to download the data from a website,I printed first 3 parameters. It seems that `char*ptr` is the memory address that data stored (as 'char a[]'?), and  `size` is element's size, nmemb is number of the elements. So the data size = size * nmemb. Am I correct?

The output is confusing too:

```
open successfully
sizeof(ptr):4
sizeof(char):1
size:1
nmemb:2715 
open successfully
sizeof(ptr):4
sizeof(char):1
size:1
nmemb:4865
download successfully
```

**When download the same url, nmemb and files' open times often change.**

I'm also confused about 'sizeof(ptr)', it returns '4'(size of int?). How can I use the 'sizeof' to get the size of data memory, so that I can **proof** that **data size is 'size * nmemb'?**

```
CURLcode download(char* url,char* out){
    CURL *curl = NULL;
    //FILE *fp = NULL;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, out);    //fp
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        return CURLE_FAILED_INIT;
    }
}    

int main()
{
    CURLcode res = download("http://XXXXXX.gif", "D:\\test.gif");
    if (CURLE_OK == res)
        cout << "download successfully.\n" << endl;
    else
        cout<<"cannot download.\n"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: In case you didn't notice, your write-function for your first code list always writes its data at the *beginning* of the file. Unless your function is only called *once*, I'm not surprised at all it doesn't match having curl do the file IO for you.

Comment: There's another thing I noticed. You create an `fstream`, which is then only used for writing. How about using an `ofstream` instead, which statically (i.e. at compile time) makes sure you only use it for that? Further, you then check if the stream is open, which is completely impossible! Simply use `ofstream file(out, ios_base::binary);`. Later, you explicitly `close()` it and `clear()` the streamstate, which is redundant because you don't use the stream after that. Instead, `flush()` the stream and then verify the streamstate for error checking. All this doesn't explain your problems though.

Comment: BTW, the very definition of `sizeof` is that it returns the size in multiples of a `char`, so by that definition `sizeof (char)` is exactly one. Always.

Comment: `ptr` is just a pointer to the data - it has nothing to do with the amount of data being provided to the callback.  You noted the documentation that indicates how Curl passes the size of the data buffer to the callback.  There's no way (other than testing by downloading a URL whose data you know by other means) to 'prove' that the amount of data being passed to the callback is `size * nmemb` - those two parameters are how Curl tells you the data size.  You'll just have to take Curl's word for it.

Answer (score 5):

This callback can be multiple times per file. You should NOT create a new file stream every time the function is called - you should pass it in using the user data parameter. Otherwise you will just keep overwriting the data at the beginning of the file.

Here is an example implementation:

```
size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    std::ofstream *out = static_cast<std::ofstream *>(userdata);
    size_t nbytes = size * nmemb;
    out->write(ptr, nbytes);
    return nbytes;
}
```

You also need to adjust the call to `curl_easy_setopt` with the parameter `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` to actually pass your file stream. Make sure that the stream does not go out of scope while the functions run!

```
CURLcode download(char* url, char* out) {
    CURL *curl = NULL;
    std::ofstream output(out, ios::binary);
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &output);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        return CURLE_FAILED_INIT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong but does this not create a memory leak?? the output file is not closed before the function returns??

Comment: It's closed when the std::ofstream object goes out of scope and its destructor runs.